# How to prevent duplication in firebase records

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an e-commerce app and i'm trying to get every item the user presses to add to their cart (functionsCombined() gets called) to be saved in firebase but i dont' want duplication in the records.

```
this.state = {
    added: false,
    duplicate: false,
}

componentWillMount() {
    //gets the data in firebase
    this.props.fetchData();
}

functionsCombined(recipe) {
    //the user pressed add to cart
    //recipe is the item to be added
    if (this.state.added) {

    } else {
        this.functionZero(recipe);
        this.functionOne();
        this.functionTwo(recipe);
    }
}

functionZero(recipe) {
    //this.props.check is the data we pulled from firebase
    //to check if the firebase records is the same as the one here
    /but even when that's true, setState doesn't work for some reason
    this.props.check.map((one) => {
        if (one.id === recipe.id) {
            this.setState({
                duplicate: true
            })
        } else {

        }
    })
}


functionOne() {
    this.setState({
        added: true
    })
}

functionTwo(recipe) {
    if (this.state.duplicate === false) {
        const {
            currentUser
        } = firebase.auth();
        firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/recipes`)
            .push(recipe);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) before saving to the firebase.
Something like this

const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

```
..... 
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/recipes`+uuidv4())
            .push(recipe);

.....
```

this will generate unique id for every firebase record that you save

Comment: This is not necessary as Firebase has that functionality built in with push() or .childByAutoId (Swift) - it will generate a unique key when the node is created. Conceptually though, it is correct.

Comment: how do I get the file's URL?